# Enabled IPv6 Nic causes network connectivity issues

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter, ipv6, windows-server-2012

I am having issues with network connectivity while PC NIC's have IPv6 enabled. My organization does not utilize IPv6. Actually, the network admins here don't have any clue how to. I have come to the conclusion that due to our lack of IPv6 knowledge and configuration, we are having network issues.

In order to circumvent the issues we are experiencing, I have been advice to disable IPv6 on all NIC's. If I forget to do this, some computers cannot connect to the internet or communicate on the network.

Is there any obvious reason this may be happening? We are strictly an IPv4 network and use DHCP to pass out IPs. IPv6 is not configured on DHCP.

Comment: The most likely cause is that something is sending bogus Router Advertisements to the network. There might be a serious security issue that is being ignored by turning off IPv6...

Comment: I would agree. How can I track down where the issue is coming from. For the past 2 years there have been serious issues...latency, connectivity. Its being ignored by everyone but me...

Comment: You would have to look at the network traffic with a tool like Wireshark and see if there is any IPv6 traffic (surprise: usually there is, even if IPv6 is not configured). Look out for RA (Router Advertisement) packets, which are an ICMP type.

Comment: Could rouge IPv6 packets be clogging the network? It seems we have extreme network slowdown during peak times. The funny thing is we only have maybe 30-35 people on the network at any given one time and the network crawls... I also think it may be network traffic from camera system.... we segment traffic through vlans so it tends to be difficult to diagnose...

Comment: @NateS. IPv6 does not cause so much background noise, that it would bring down a network. More likely you are seeing high load due to whatever those users need to transfer over the network and/or delays due to hosts attempting IPv6 connections and trying for several seconds before timing out and switching to IPv4. I agree that using Wireshark to look for router advertisements is a good start. Also verify what the routing table looks like on a machine which has problems.